# How to hide the AppBar when persistent BottomSheet is expanded?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, bottom-sheet, android-appbarlayout

I have a FragmentContainerView with bottomsheet behavior. I want it to expand to the top of the screen, hiding the AppBar.

How do I make it so that when the bottom sheet is dragged up, it collapses the AppBar? It should also not expand the AppBar again when scrolling the NestedScrollView in the bottomsheet's fragment.

It also has to restore previous AppBar behavior when in landscape mode after it is dragged down again (The AppBar hides on scroll in landscape mode)

This is what I've tried, but it doesn't work, the appbar just stays as it is:

```
 bottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {

            if(newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {


                AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) myToolbar.getLayoutParams();
                appBarLayout.setExpanded(false);
                params.setScrollFlags(0);

            } else if(newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) myToolbar.getLayoutParams();

                if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
                    params.setScrollFlags(0);
                } else {
                    params.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SNAP);
                   
                }

                appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling across this issue:

Add a custom behaviour to the AppBar that prevents it from scrolling when the event comes from the bottom sheet. To prevent the toolbar from collapsing when scrolling, but also being able to collapse it through code, also block the scrolling when the device is in portrait mode (Checked through a static variable in MainActivity which gets updated by onConfigurationChange)

```
class AppBarBehavior extends AppBarLayout.Behavior {

public AppBarBehavior() {
}

public AppBarBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

private boolean mIsSheetTouched = false;




@Override
public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child,
                                   View directTargetChild, View target, int axes, int type) {
    // Set flag if the bottom sheet is responsible for the nested scroll.
    mIsSheetTouched = target.getId() == R.id.bottom_sheet_scroll_view;

    // Only consider starting a nested scroll if the bottom sheet is not touched; otherwise,
    // we will let the other views do the scrolling.


    return !mIsSheetTouched && !MainActivity.portrait
            && super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, directTargetChild,
            target, axes, type);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(CoordinatorLayout parent, AppBarLayout child, MotionEvent ev) {
    // Don't accept touch stream here if the bottom sheet is touched. This will permit the
    // bottom sheet to be dragged down without interaction with the appBar. Reset on cancel.
    if (ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
        mIsSheetTouched = false;
    }
    return !mIsSheetTouched && !MainActivity.portrait && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(parent, child, ev);
}}
```

Add the custom behavior to the appbarlayout like this

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior=".AppBarBehavior">
```

Now to collapse and expand the appbar with the bottom sheet, just do this

```
    FragmentContainerView bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
    AppBarLayout appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout);
    bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);


    bottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {

            if(newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {    
     
                appBarLayout.setExpanded(false);
         
            } else if(newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING) {
            
                if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                    appBarLayout.setExpanded(true);
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

        }
    });
```